# Remove text after certain word

Tags: php, text-processing

I have dynamic link build from variable :

> /Tinkle/Matte/BlackHyper/Black/Gunmetal

How can I remove all text after variable value "BlackHyper" to become:
 "/Tinkle/Matte/BlackHyper"

I try rtrim :

> $param="**BlackHyper**";
>     $str="/Tinkle/Matte/**BlackHyper**/Black/Gunmetal";
>     rtrim($str,$param);

No luck , remove some letters....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTrim doesnt work like this.

You need to do something like this

```
$pos = strpos($str, $param);
$endpoint = $pos + strlen($param);
$newStr = substr($str,0,$endpoint );
```

This will create a new string (there might be a bug or two I havent tested it) with all characters up to your param.

Comment: OP wants to incelude `$param` in the result, so you should use `$pos+strlen($param)`.

Comment: newStr will contain the changed string, $str will remain the same.  Thats the way it works!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use strstr function?

```
$a = "before/after";
$b = strstr($a, "/",true); // gets text before /
$c = strstr($a, "/"); // gets text after /
```